# Ext Js: make button a link

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

In Ext Js I want some of my buttons to work like links (i.e. `<a href...`).

How can I do that.

Right now I am adding a handler that does `window.location.href=http://....`.

But I thought there should be an easier way - something like adding an href attribute like in menu item.

Some ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, that's actually the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: For ExtJS Modern 6.x (6.5) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494458/extjs-6-x-modern-button-as-a-link/47519792#47519792

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also an existing [user extension](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?80639-Ext.LinkButton-A-button-class-which-renders-an-lt-a-gt-element.) that does exactly this.

Answer (score 7):

That's the way it's done... To be more portable you could extend `Ext.Button` into `Ext.ux.LinkButton` (or whatever) and implement the property and the required behavior in this extended class (just a quick-&-dirty example):

```
Ext.ux.LinkButton = Ext.extend(Ext.Button, {
    href: null,
    handler: function() {
        if (this.href) {
            window.location.href = this.href;
        }
    } 
}); 
Ext.reg( "ux-linkbutton", Ext.ux.LinkButton );

var btn = new Ext.ux.LinkButton({
    text: "Link to Google",
    href: "http://www.google.com"
});
```

**EDIT:**

Simple change of appearance:

```
Ext.ux.LinkButton = Ext.extend(Ext.Button, {
    href: null,
    template: new Ext.Template(
        ['<table id="{4}" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn {3}"><tbody class="{1}">',
        '<tr><td class="x-btn-tl"><i>&#160;</i></td><td class="x-btn-tc"></td><td class="x-btn-tr"><i>&#160;</i></td></tr>',
        '<tr><td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&#160;</i></td><td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="{2}" unselectable="on"><a href="{0}"></a></em></td><td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&#160;</i></td></tr>',
        '<tr><td class="x-btn-bl"><i>&#160;</i></td><td class="x-btn-bc"></td><td class="x-btn-br"><i>&#160;</i></td></tr>',
        '</tbody></table>'], {compiled: true}),
    buttonSelector : 'a:first-child',
    getTemplateArgs : function(){
        return [this.href, 'x-btn-' + this.scale + ' x-btn-icon-' + this.scale + '-' + this.iconAlign, this.getMenuClass(), this.cls, this.id];
    },
    handler: function(b, e) {
        if (this.href) {
            e.stopEvent();
            window.location.href = this.href;
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: thank you. Why can't it be like in menu item (so when the user hovers he can see where the link will take him in the status bar)

Comment: To do that you have to override the rendering of the button element to actually render a `<a>`-tag with an `href`-attribute. This shouldn't be too complicated - see my edit above (please note that this is untested and not a throughout solution...

Comment: This does not seem to work in ExtJS 4; would it be difficult to modify it to work in ExtJS4?

Comment: @ErikAllik That's because the class system (including the inheritance) has changed with Ext JS 4. If you just want a button that follows a link on click, you can use the `href`-config of the Ext JS 4 button. Changing the appearance is somewhat different but easier. You should open a follow-up question regarding overriding the appearance of Ext JS components.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `e.stopEvent()`. That's what I was looking for.