# how to create a button that links to textfile/excel sheet/url (EXTJS)?

Tags: extjs

I need to create a button that links to textfile/excel sheet/url.How to do the same in EXTJS ? Can anyone help me with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
new Ext.Button({
  text: 'PRESS ME',
  handler: function() {
    window.open('http://textfiles.com/or/spreadsheet.xls', '_blank');
  }
});
```

Or possibly `window.location = http://somewhereelse.com/anotherfile.txt'` in the handler if you don't want to open a new window.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `Ext.LinkButton` (an extension you have to add your self) made by [**Animal**](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?80639-Ext.LinkButton-A-button-class-which-renders-an-lt-a-gt-element.) and it works very well.

It uses an *HTML* `<a href...>` element so it acts as a normal link. I have had some troubles with **wombleton**'s solution, because the browser might ask the user if it is okay to open this *popup* - due to the use of *JavaScript methods*.

You can also see the reference from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544643/ext-js-make-button-a-link) here on [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).